# How to make console app display in browser with React?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router

I made a simple weather app for a course I'm taking and I would like it to display in the browser. Right now, the app only works in the console. I've made a very simple front-end for it with React, and I can't figure out how to combine the two.

Here's the weather app:

```
const yargs = require('yargs');
const axios = require('axios');

const argv = yargs
  .options({
    a: {
      demand: true,
      alias: 'address',
      describe: 'Address to fetch weather for',
      string: true
    }
})
.help()
.alias('help', 'h')
.argv;

var encodedAddress = encodeURIComponent(argv.address);
var geocodeUrl = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?
address=${encodedAddress}`;

axios.get(geocodeUrl).then((response) => {
    if(response.data.status === 'ZERO_RESULTS'){
        throw new Error('Unable to find that address.');
    }

    var lat = response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
    var lng = response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
    var weatherUrl = `https://api.darksky.net/forecast/c19cc88150a85b69753b7fc23e3ca99d/${lat},${lng}`;

    console.log(response.data.results[0].formatted_address);
    return axios.get(weatherUrl);
}).then((response) => {
    var temperature = response.data.currently.temperature;
    var apparentTemperature = response.data.currently.apparentTemperature;
    console.log(`It's currently ${temperature}. It feels like 
${apparentTemperature}`);
}).catch((e) => {
    if(e.code === 'ENOTFOUND'){
        console.log('Unable to connect to API servers.');
    } else {
        console.log(e.message);
    }
});
```

So, I've pretty much just created a basic form with a text box to enter a location and a submit button. How do I make it search the lattitude/longitude, find the weather, and display that on the screen?

Here is the React page, it's very simple, I'll of course add onto when I figure out how to display what I want it to:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Homepage extends Component {
  render() {
   return (
    <div className="container-fluid">

        <h1>
            Weather
        </h1>
        <form action="/weather">
            <div id="address" className="form-group">
                <input className="form-control" type="text" name="address" placeholder="Location" />
            </div>
            <div id="address" className="form-group">
                <button className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Search!</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    );
  }
}


export default Homepage;
```

Comment: So, the code you posted works, correct? You tested it in the console, you get JSON data in return, and now you want to plug it into your React front-end? Can you show the code for the React front-end you've written so far, because there is zero React in the code you posted.

Comment: Yes, that code works. I just edited the post to include the React 'homepage'. It's literally just what you get when you 'create-react-app' plus that page. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've moved the API calls directly inside the component for simplicity's sake, but in a real project you'd want to keep them separate and import them.

I've also added a very simple div to display the results of the search (only if it's fully successful). Let me know if this works, and if you have any questions.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class Homepage extends Component {
  // constructor to initialize state
  contructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      address: '',
      temperature: '',
      apparentTemperature: '',
      lat: '',
      lng: ''
    }
  }
  // handler for 'address' controlled input
  onChangeAddress = (e) => {
    this.setState({ address: e.target.value });
  }
  // execute search
  doSearch = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const encodedAddress = encodeURIComponent(this.state.address);
    const geocodeUrl = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=${encodedAddress}`;

    axios.get(geocodeUrl).then((response) => {
      if(response.data.status === 'ZERO_RESULTS'){
        throw new Error('Unable to find that address.');
      }
      this.setState({
        lat: response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lat,
        lng: response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lng
      });
      const weatherUrl = `https://api.darksky.net/forecast/c19cc88150a85b69753b7fc23e3ca99d/${this.state.lat},${this.state.lng}`;

      console.log(response.data.results[0].formatted_address);
      return axios.get(weatherUrl);
    }).then((response) => {
      this.setState({
        temperature: response.data.currently.temperature,
        apparentTemperature: response.data.currently.apparentTemperature
      });
      console.log(`It's currently ${this.state.temperature}. It feels like ${this.state.apparentTemperature}`);
    }).catch((e) => {
      if(e.code === 'ENOTFOUND'){
        console.log('Unable to connect to API servers.');
      } else {
        console.log(e.message);
      }
    });
  }
  render() {
    const { lat, lng, address, temperature, apparentTemperature } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <h1>
          Weather
        </h1>
//        { lat !== '' && lng !== '' && temperature !== '' && apparentTemperature !== '' &&
          <div className="weather-info">
            address: {address}<br />
            latitude: {lat}<br />
            longitude: {lng}<br />
            temperature: {temperature}<br />
            feels like: {apparentTemperature}
          </div>
//        }
        <form>
          <div id="address" className="form-group">
            <input className="form-control" type="text" name="address" placeholder="Location" value={address} onChange={this.onChangeAddress} />
          </div>
          <div id="address" className="form-group">
            <button className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" onClick={this.doSearch}>Search!</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Homepage;
```

Comment: Thank you, but nothing displays no matter what I submit.

Comment: Anything in the console? Do you see the API calls being fired as XHR in the Network tab of the Chrome dev tools? Anything at all other than "it's not working"?

Comment: I can see the formatted address pop up in the console for a split second and then it goes back to nothing. I do see the API calls being fired in the Network tab

Comment: I don't understand. It's a log, how can a log disappear unless you manually clear it? This is in the Chrome dev tools console, right?

Comment: And they fire each time you submit a search? Also, do you see both calls (google & darksky), or just one?

Comment: Try logging `weatherUrl` just after you log the formatted address, and then test that URL in the browser to see if you do get back data. With the code I've posted, you'll only see results if BOTH api calls are successful. Also, try commenting out the condition test around the results div. I've updated my code to comment them out. This way you'll see if you get back the latitude & longitude (or anything else).

Comment: Sorry, took me a good minute to screenshot the fraction of a second that the weatherUrl was in the log. The URL worked fine. The div is displaying now with the condition test commented out. It shows the latitude and longitude for the same split second that stuff appears in the console. 

Here is what I see in the Network tab, also for just a split second before disappearing: https://imgur.com/a/wKfJh

Comment: Thank you. I still don't understand why the logs & network calls are cleared. Does the page reload? Still, we know that (a) the address is correctly submitted (b) the search method is triggered (c) the googleapi request is successful and (d) the latitude & longitude are correctly updated. We even know that the darksky api request is correctly sent, and according to your screenshot, the lat & long are properly passed.

Comment: The page does reload, how do we prevent that?

Comment: Ah, I have an idea. Is it possible that the form is actually submitted (in a regular HTML way) when you press the button? It shouldn't be the case since I removed the action, and it's a button not a submit tag, but you could try removing the form tags to make sure. Other than that I see no reason why the page would reload, but I don't know what exactly is in your entire code.

Comment: @BadAtJS I've added an `e.preventDefault()` statement in the `doSearch` method, it should prevent any form submission/page reload when you click the search button, and this way you can leave the form tags in your code. My bad, should've put that statement in from the beginning, would've saved us some trouble!

Comment: Thank you, but I suppose I really don't need the form. Thanks again, though, you're the best!